# how to replace the 'connectionstring' that is in a dll file?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, helper

i mean: how to override a connectionstring ? it's possible? I tried a few things in the file 'Site.master' but no sucess ;/

thx.

Comment: We need more information about where you are currently getting your ConnectionString from. At the moment your question is to vague and ambiguous.

Comment: take a look in your web.config file, that is where ASP.NET typically keeps connection strings.

Comment: I will explain, I have a system that has been done by someone else, I'm not asp.net programmer, but i need to move that site to another server and need to change the connectionstring, but it is inside a dll.

how can i override it without edit the dll?

Comment: If the connection string is IN the dll, then your programmer should have absolutely given you the source code that you can recompile. HOWEVER, the connection string "should" be in the web.config by default... are you absolutely sure it's compiled? if it is, you'll need the source.

Comment: yes, i can see with dis .net decompiler, look:

[DefaultSettingValue("Data Source= ~

inside Library.Properties.

but maybe i could override it? it's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to read a connection string from the app.config file from a referenced project (DAL -- Data Access Layer) instead of from the `executable project (the web site)`. You need to copy the config settings connection string to your website's `web.config` file.

When you run your website and call to the DB from your dll, it will pick the connection string from the web.config file of your website.